# How to tell Kibana to read a container name having dash inside as a single string

Tags: kubernetes, kibana

I need to use Kibana to search the logs of my container, whose name is `ABCDE-prod`.

So in the KQL field I put

```
kubernetes.container.name.keyword is ABCDE-prod
```

But then Kibana treats the dash (`-`) as a space, and so the query becomes the equivalent of

```
kubernetes.container.name.keyword is ABCDE
OR
kubernetes.container.name.keyword is prod
```

How can I tell KIbana to treat ABCDE-prod as a single string?

I tryed with

```
kubernetes.container.name.keyword is "ABCDE-prod"
```

but it returns this error log:

> Error loading data
>
> Expected ":", "<", "<=", ">", ">=", AND, OR, end of input, whitespace
> but """ found. kubernetes.container.name.keyword is "ABCDE-prod"
> -------------------------------------^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!

```
kubernetes.container.name.keyword is ABCDE-prod
```

must not be put in the KQL field, but added as a filter, with the button just below the KQL field:

**+add filter** > filter widget:

> select filter: `kubernetes.container.name.keyword`
>
> select operator: `is`
>
> select value: `ABCDE-prod`

this automatically creates a filter that searches the logs of `ABCDE-prod`.